# How to design an application so that one user cannot concurrently do separate transactions in database from 2 separate browser at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I am designing an Banking application ,kindly help me to develop how can I block a user who is accessing  his/her bank account concurrently from two separate browsers(systems).Suppose the user is withdrawing money from his/her account concurrently from  two browsers at the same type ,how can I stop the user from doing so?

Comment: There are quite a few parts existing between the browser at one end and the SQL Server database at the other, and you wouldn't usually try to solve this issue purely down at the database level. I.e. you'd normally have a concept of *sessions* that are maintained by cookies and establish a context between browser and web server(s). It would usually be far more normal to look into solutions that e.g. terminate older sessions when a new session is established for the same user.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a flag column named SessionActive datatype int with the customer table.
- Let the column value be 0 when the user did not log into his account anywhere.
- If an user log into his/her account from a browser, he/she could be authenticated to his/her account only when the flag is 0 ie. SessionActive=0.
- Update the flag to 1 ie. set SessionActive = 1 soon after he logged into his account.
- Update the flag to 0 ie. set SessionActive = 0 when he/she log out.